# Why can't a list of an interface type accept instances of an inheriting interface?

Tags: c#, list, types, interface

Given the following types:

```
public interface IPrimary{ void doBattle(); }

// an ISecondary "is" an IPrimary
public interface ISecondary : IPrimary {  }

// An implementation of ISecondary is also an IPrimary:
internal class SecondaryImpl : ISecondary
{
    // Required, since this is an IPrimary
    public void doBattle(){ }
}
```

Why can I not do this?

```
List<IPrimary> list = new List<ISecondary>();
```

This results in the following compilation error:

> Argument type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

I understand the error, and I realize there are workarounds. I just do not see any clear reason why this direct conversion is disallowed. The values contained in a list of `ISecondary`, should after all, be (by extension) values of type of `IPrimary`.Why then are `List<IPrimary>` and `List<ISecondary>` being interpreted as unrelated types?

**Can anyone explain clearly the reasoning for C# being designed this way?**

*A slightly extended example:* I came across the issue when trying to do something similar to the following:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Instance of ISecondary, and by extention, IPrimary:
        var mySecondaryInstance = new SecondaryImpl();

        // This works as expected:
        AcceptImpl(mySecondaryInstance);

        // List of instances of ISecondary, which are also, 
        // by extention, instances of IPrimary:
        var myListOfSecondaries = new List<ISecondary> {mySecondaryInstance};

        // This, however, does not work (results in a compilation error):
        AcceptList(myListOfSecondaries);
    }

    // Note: IPrimary parameter:
    public static void AcceptImpl(IPrimary instance){  }

    // Note: List of type IPrimary:
    public static void AcceptList(List<IPrimary> list){  }

}
```

Comment: You want to look at "Generics Covariance in C#"

Comment: [Covariance and contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee207183.aspx). And `List<IPrimary> list = new List<ISecondary>();` makes no sense to actually do, even if you could.

Comment: @GrantThomas Ok, maybe a bit simplified there; but what about `someListOfTypePrimary.AddRange(someProvider.getListOftypeSecondary());`? Is there some reason this should not occur?

Comment: I think that should be allowed, since `AddRange` takes `IEnumerable<T>` type, which does support covariance - `IEnumerable<ISecondary>` can be used anywhere `IEnumerable<IPrimary>` can be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why can I not do this? `List<IPrimary> list = new List<ISecondary>();`

Imagine that you had a method defined like this:

```
public void PopulateList(List<IPrimary> listToPopulate)
{
    listToPopulate.Add(new Primary());  // Primary does not implement ISecondary!
}
```

What would happen if you were to pass it a `List<ISecondary>` as a parameter?

The error that *`List<ISecondary>` is not assignable from `List<IPrimary>`* is the compiler's way of getting you out of such troubles.

Answer (score 11):

```
public class Animal
{
    ...
}

public class Cat: Animal
{
    public void Meow(){...}
}

List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>();

cats.Add(new Cat());

cats[0].Meow();  // Fine.

List<Animal> animals = cats; // Pretend this compiles.

animals.Add(new Animal()); // Also adds an Animal to the cats list, since animals references cats.

cats[1].Meow(); // cats[1] is an Animal, so this explodes!
```

And that's why.

Comment: Thanks! +1 for an insightful and humorous example. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
class Evil : IPrimary {...}
list.Add(new Evil()); // valid c#, but wouldn't work
```

It is protecting you from an error. The list instance (the object) demands secondary instances. Not every primary is a secondary. Yet the expectation is that a list-of-primary can hold *any primary*. If we could treat a list-of-secondary as a list-of-primary: bad things.

Actually, arrays *do* allow this - and error at runtime if you get it wrong.

Comment: Thanks, nice explanation. Appreciate the side note about arrays too.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that list types are not covariant in their generic parameter ie that `List<ISecondary>` is not a subtype of `List<IPrimary>` is that they are read-write. In your extended example your method `AcceptList` could do `list.Add(x)` where `x` is an `IPrimary` but not an `ISecondary`.

Note that `IEnumerable<T>` is correctly covariant, while arrays are typed covariantly (you can do what you try to above) but for the same reason this is not sound - adding an element to the collection will fail at runtime.