# Returning subtype of IEnumerable in Dictionary not possible

Tags: c#, dictionary, ienumerable, ilist

Why is this a problem in C#?

```
public Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>> GetProducts() {
    return new Dictionary<string, IList<object>>();
}
```

Comment: Jakob -- please be more descriptive of your problem in the future. It appears your question was able to be answered this time, but having a detailed explanation of the problem is helpful to those trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, because it would creata a dictionary, having `IList<object>` as a value.

So if you would call:

```
IEnumerable<object> values = someOtherObjectCollectionPerhapseSomethingFromLinq;
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>> products = GetProducts();
products.Add("MyKey", values);
```

Your returning dictionary will accept the `IEnumerable<object>` but the dictionary underneat will not accept it, since it values HAVE TO BE of type `IList<object>`, which in this is, it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can't return this:

```
new Dictionary<string, IList<object>>();
```

.. but you can return this:

```
new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>>();
```

.. or change your return-type:

```
public Dictionary<string, IList<object>> GetProducts(){ ... }
```

Part of the reasoning behind this:

Imagine if you could get the returned Dictionary as a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>>`, but with the values as `List<object>` instead of `IEnumerable<object>`(where `List` is a more specific type of `IEnumerable`).

If you then tried to add a new `IEnumerable<object>` to it, that would be an invalid operation, since your elements are not, in fact, of type `IEnumerable<object>`, but rather `List<object>`.

The reason *that* is disallowed, is that an element of type `List<object>` might (and does) contain methods that an `IEnumerable<object>` does not.

Imagine adding an element of type `IEnumerable<object>` to a `Dictionary<string, List<object>>`. That would mean that you could call a `List<object>`-specific method on each element *until* you reached the first `IEnumerable<object>`-element, where that method would not be defined, and therefor throw an exception.

Your original code causes a compile-time error to stop you from ever getting into problems such as this.

I myself asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621564/why-cant-a-list-of-an-interface-type-accept-intances-of-an-inheriting-interface) not too long ago, which might be helpful to understand this better.