# Generic argument not assignable

Tags: c#, generics

I'm using C#.NET 3.5. I get

> argument type 'GenericTest.BarkStrategy' is not assignible to parameter type 'GenericsTest.IAnimalStrategy'

with the following (for this question as much simplified as possible) code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GenericsTest {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            List<IAnimalStrategy<IAnimal>> strategies = 
                new List<IAnimalStrategy<IAnimal>>();
            strategies.Add(new BarkStrategy());
        }
    }

    interface IAnimal { }
    interface IAnimalStrategy<T> where T : IAnimal { }
    class Dog : IAnimal { }
    class BarkStrategy : IAnimalStrategy<Dog> { }
}
```

Comment: This problem has basically been answered in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621564/why-cant-a-list-of-an-interface-type-accept-intances-of-an-inheriting-interface).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to tell the compiler that your interface is covariant : `IAnimalStrategy<out T>`

```
namespace GenericsTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<IAnimalStrategy<IAnimal>> strategies = new List<IAnimalStrategy<IAnimal>>();
            strategies.Add(new BarkStrategy());
        }
    }

    interface IAnimal { }
    interface IAnimalStrategy<out T> where T : IAnimal { }

    class Dog : IAnimal { }
    class BarkStrategy : IAnimalStrategy<Dog> { }
}
```

Unfortunately, it is available only in C# 4.0 : [How is Generic Covariance & Contra-variance Implemented in C# 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-is-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implemented-in-c-sharp-4-0)

For understanding the problem, you can forget the list, this line doesn't compile :

```
IAnimalStrategy<IAnimal> s = new BarkStrategy();
```

The `IAnimalStrategy<IAnimal>` interface can do things on IAnimal, maybe set a property of type `IAnimal`

```
interface IAnimalStrategy<T> where T : IAnimal 
{
    T Animal {get; set;}
}
```

Then you would be able to do something like

```
IAnimalStrategy<IAnimal> s = new BarkStrategy();
s.Animal = new Cat();
```

It will blow in your face. So C#3.5 doesn't allow you to do that.
C#4.0 will allow you to that, if you said that T is covariant with the `out` keyword

```
interface IAnimalStrategy<out T> where T : IAnimal 
{
    T Animal {get; set;}
}
```

This will blow again,

> Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on
> IAnimalStrategy.Animal'. 'T' is covariant.

Covariance and Contravariance are difficults to understand, I suggest you read the awesome series on Eric Lippert's Blog : [Covariance and Contravariance in C#](https://web.archive.org/web/20151107135457/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx)